# How to add columns to customer address grid in admin?

Tags: magento2, collection, customer-address, join-table, custom-column-grid

I have to add two fields to the customer's address grid, for this I have to add a left join to the Magento collection. I have created the following custom module:

**Vendor/Module/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_address_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_address_columns">
        <column name="first_field">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">11</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">First Field</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="second_field">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">12</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Second Field</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Address\Grid\Collection">
        <plugin name="customer_address_grid_collection" type="\Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\ResourceModel\Address\Collection"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/Model/Plugin/ResourceModel/Address/Collection.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\ResourceModel\Address; 
 
class Collection
{
 
    public static $table = 'customer_address_entity';
    public static $leftJoinTable = 'customer_address_entity_varchar'; 

 
    public function beforeLoad($intercepter, $collection)
    {        
        if ($collection->getMainTable() === $collection->getConnection()->getTableName(self::$table)) {
 
            $leftJoinTableName = $collection->getConnection()->getTableName(self::$leftJoinTable);
 
            $collection 
                ->getSelect()
                ->joinLeft(
                    ['first_field_table'=>$leftJoinTableName],
                    'main_table.entity_id = first_field_table.entity_id and first_field_table.attribute_id=188',
                    [
                        'first_field'=>'first_field_table.value'
                    ]
                )->joinLeft(
                    ['second_field_table'=>$leftJoinTableName],
                    'main_table.entity_id = second_field_table.entity_id and second_field_table.attribute_id=189',
                    [
                        'second_field'=>'second_field_table.value'                   
                    ]
                );
 
            $where = $collection->getSelect()->getPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE);
 
            $collection->getSelect()->setPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE, $where)->group('main_table.entity_id');
 
            echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();die;
        }
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

The columns appear in the grid but do not include any fields. I have put a logger in my Collection.php class but it does not run, I have also tried removing a semicolon from this class so that it breaks but nothing happens, therefore it is not going through the class at any time.

If anyone can help me I would really appreciate it.
I am using Magento version 2.3.5-p1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your module's `di.xml`. The plugin gets loaded just fine for me on 2.3.4. Is your module properly enabled?

```
php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Module
```

And did you clean cache/generated after enabling?

After making sure that is done. Your beforeLoad should also be changed. This is the function signature from `Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb`:

```
public function load($printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
```

So your beforeLoad should return these parameters instead of `$collection`:

```
public function beforeLoad($collection, $printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
    {        
        
        if (...) {
            $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(...)
            ...Etc
        }

        return [$printQuery, $logQuery];
    }
```

If your plugin is still not loaded after enabling the module and clearing generated, then there might be another module interfering or overriding `Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Address\Grid\Collection`.

Comment: Works! The error was in the parameters of the function and the return, I have modified it as you say in your answer and it already works perfectly. Thank you very much.